# While passing data using intent from activity to receiver null pointer Exception in oreo version

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

While passing datas from an activity using intent , null pointer Exception occurs in Oreo. The data gets added to the intent but while logging it in reciever class the datas are null. Any suggestions in this issue. This occurs only in Oreo.

Code:
 in MainActivity:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    myIntent.setClass(this, MyReceiver.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("model", model);
    Log.d("model main activty", model.getName() + "");
    startService(myIntent);

    //sendBroadcast(myIntent);
    requestCode++;
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, requestCode, myIntent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) 
   getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    assert alarmManager != null;
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 
   pendingIntent);
```

in Reciever Class:public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Model model = intent.getParcelableExtra("model");
    Log.d("model receiver", model.getName() + "");
    new NotificationGenerator().generateNotification(context, intent);
}
```

}

here null pointer occurs in the reciever class

Comment: could you provide your code? we can't solve by guessing.

Comment: @ZaidMirza i have added the code